# Wagmi "useAccount" connector is undefined after refreshing page using next.js

Tags: walletconnect, wagmi, nextjs, rainbowkit

I am using WAGMI and the Rainbowkit connector for my Dapp. After deploying it on production, I have encountered a strange problem. Sometimes, after refreshing the page or opening it in a new tab, the "connector" and useWalletclient "data" become undefined randomly. I have spent a lot of time digging through the internet but couldn't find any solution. Any hints or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

import { useWalletClient, useAccount, useConnect } from 'wagmi'
import Web3 from 'web3'

export const useGetProviderInfo = () => {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false)
  const { data, isIdle } = useWalletClient()
  console.log(' ~ file: useGetProviderInfo.tsx:9 ~ useGetProviderInfo ~ isIdle:', isIdle)
  const { connect } = useConnect()
  const { address: account, isConnected, connector } = useAccount()
  console.log(' ~ file: useGetProviderInfo.tsx:12 ~ useGetProviderInfo ~ connector:', connector)
  const library = new Web3(data as any)
  // useEffect(() => {
  //   if (isIdle) {
  //     connect()
  //   }
  // }, [isIdle])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isConnected && library.currentProvider) {
      setActive(true)
    } else {
      setActive(false)
    }
  }, [account, isConnected, library.currentProvider])

  return { library, account, active }
}
```

Demo: [url](https://sandbox-snowy-ten.vercel.app/)
SendBox: [url](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/sleepy-mcnulty-5v99gn?file=%2Fpages%2F_app.tsx%3A22%2C4)

[Issue on github with video](https://github.com/wagmi-dev/wagmi/issues/2784)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you already try to call `error` from `useWalletClient`.

It can show the exact problem.

```
const { data, isIdle, error, isError } = useWalletClient()

useEffect(() => {
  console.log(error.message)
}, [error, isError])
```

Comment: yap, I tried above solution to find if any errors are returned but `error` is `null`

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is an issue with the render. You can create a new component for the account balance and import it with the client side render.

```
const Profile = dynamic(() => import("./Profile"), {
  ssr: false,
});
```

Then in the `Profile.tsx` component file, you can use the `useAccount()` import.
This worked for me. Hope this helps.

Also, if you, later on, need the address, you may put it in a context globally to access rather than using `useAccount()` all the time.